# Kentico Admin - Page Types Custom Form Layout

Tags: kentico

I notice that for a custom page type, under Layout, we can add some customization to it. The question is if my list of Authors (each is a checkbox) is very long, is it possible to display the list into 2 or more columns? If yes, how to edit the code below to make that happen. Thanks for help!

```
    <tr class="form-table-group">
      <td class="form-table-label-cell">$$label:Authors$$</td>
      <td class="form-table-value-cell">$$input:Authors$$</td>
      <td class="form-table-validation-cell">$$validation:Authors$$</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done in the configuration of that field. Please go to Page Types -> your page type -> Fields -> Authors, click Advanced, and choose Table layout and 2 Repeat columns.